# How do I create a built distribution for the OSX platform in Python?

Tags: python, distutils, software-distribution

I have a package of pure python modules that I'd like to create a nice bdist for for my Apple users (I'm running Windows 7 on a AMD64-PC).

Do I just run the RPM installer in distutils?

Is there an alternative to distutils that creates "platform agnostic" installers (i.e., it installs source code and then compiles to bytecode using hosts interpreter).

Answer (score 0):

Ok...feel kinda dumb, but I found what I think is the answer:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bdist_mpkg/

Comment: Correction: This will work if you are using a Linux-based system (requires grp)...I'll need to use a source code distribution since I am on Windows.